# Add [unowned self] to the closure argument Swift

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting, unowned-references

I have a function with a completion handler, returning one parameter or more.

In a client, when executing a completion handler, I'd like to have an `unowned` reference to `self`, as well as having access to the parameter passed.

Here is the Playground example illustrating the issue and the goal I'm trying to achieve.

```
import UIKit

struct Struct {
  func function(completion: (String) -> ()) {
    completion("Boom!")
  }

  func noArgumentsFunction(completion: () -> Void) {
    completion()
  }
}

class Class2 {
  func execute() {
    Struct().noArgumentsFunction { [unowned self] in
      //...
    }

    Struct().function { (string) in // Need [unowned self] here
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Struct().function { [unowned self]  (string) in 
   //your code here }`

Comment: @richard-topchiy : And whats the issue ?? Reinier thats a good one :) I would have upvoted had it been posted as answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in my comment

```
Struct().function { [unowned self] (string) in 
    //your code here 
}
```

**Capture list** and **closure parameters** that should be the order in closures more info from [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

> **Defining a Capture List**
>
> Each item in a capture list is a pairing of
>   the weak or unowned keyword with a reference to a class instance (such
>   as self) or a variable initialized with some value (such as delegate =
>   self.delegate!). These pairings are written within a pair of square
>   braces, separated by commas.
>
> Place the capture list before a closure’s parameter list and return
>   type if they are provided:

```
lazy var someClosure: (Int, String) -> String = {
    [unowned self, weak delegate = self.delegate!] (index: Int, stringToProcess: String) -> String in
    // closure body goes here 
}
```

> If a closure does not specify a parameter list or return type because
>   they can be inferred from
>   context, place the capture list at the very start of the closure,
>   followed by the in keyword:

```
lazy var someClosure: () -> String = {
     [unowned self, weak delegate = self.delegate!] in
     // closure body goes here
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried to place `[unowned self] after the closure arguments`, which triggered a compile error.

Comment: A bit too late but place the capture list before the closure arguments, not after. And if there are no closure arguments, type `in` after the capture list.

Answer (score 1):

Is it just the syntax for including [unowned self] in the closure parameter list you need?

```
struct Struct {
    func function(completion:(String)->()) {
        completion("Boom!")
    }
}

class Class {
    func execute() {
        Struct().function { [unowned self] string in
            print(string)
            print(self)
        }
    }
}

Class().execute()
```

[image]